# What is a more formal alternative to 'downsides'?

Tags: formality

Original sentence from scientific article:
Current treatments are...[details of treatments], but there are some downsides of these treatments.

I realise that it should be 'downsides to', but I feel it could be more formal. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will find many a good [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rotation) online.

Comment: Is "treatment" a medical treatment? In which case "side-effects" may be a good answer.

Comment: No, not side effects. It has to do with kidney disease and dialysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can be used instead of "downsides":

- Negative aspects
- Cons
- Disadvantages
- Drawbacks
- Limitations